# Add Comparable Object to Sorted Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I've written an add(Comparable obj) method here: However, when I run a test on it, such as the one listed below, the printed list only consists of the most recently added item. I can't find the break in my logic.

When I try to increment theSize++ before the While loop, I receive an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Character cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Character and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')".

EDIT:Full code:

```
/**
 * Class OrderedLinkedList.
 * <p>
 * This class functions as a linked list, but ensures items are stored in ascending order.
 */
public class OrderedLinkedList {

    /**************************************************************************
     * Constants
     *************************************************************************/

    /**
     * return value for unsuccessful searches
     */
    private static final OrderedListNode NOT_FOUND = null;


    /**************************************************************************
     * Attributes
     *************************************************************************/

    /**
     * current number of items in list
     */
    private int theSize;

    /**
     * reference to list header node
     */
    private OrderedListNode head;

    /**
     * reference to list tail node
     */
    private OrderedListNode tail;

    /**
     * current number of modifications to list
     */
    private int modCount;


    /**************************************************************************
     * Constructors
     *************************************************************************/


    /**
     * Create an instance of OrderedLinkedList.
     */
    public OrderedLinkedList() {
        // empty this OrderedLinkedList
        clear();
    }


    /**************************************************************************
     * Methods
     *************************************************************************/


    /*
     *  Add the specified item to this OrderedLinkedList.
     *
     *  @param  obj     the item to be added
     */
    public boolean add(Comparable obj) {
        // TODO: Implement this method (8 points)
        OrderedListNode node = new OrderedListNode(obj, null, null);

        //if list is empty, add to beginning of list
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head.next = node;
            node.next = tail;
            tail.previous = node;

        }

        //if theItem is less than the first element, add it to the beginning of the list
        if (obj.compareTo(head.next.theItem) < 0) {
            node.next = head.next;
            head.next = node;

        }

        OrderedListNode pointer = head.next;

        while (pointer.theItem.compareTo(obj) < 0 && pointer.next != null) {
            pointer = pointer.next;
            node.previous = pointer.previous;
            node.next = pointer;
            pointer.previous.next = node;
            pointer.previous = node;

            theSize++;
            modCount++;
        }
        return true;

    }


    /*
     *  Remove the first occurrence of the specified item from this OrderedLinkedList.
     *
     *  @param  obj     the item to be removed
     */
    public boolean remove(Comparable obj) {
        // TODO: implement this method (7 points)
        OrderedListNode node = head.next;

        if (isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        while (node != null) {
            if (obj.compareTo(node) == 0) {
                node.next.previous = node.previous;
                node = node.next;
                return true;
            }

            node = node.next;
        }
        ++modCount;

        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Empty this OrderedLinkedList.
     */
    public void clear() {
        // reset header node
        head = new OrderedListNode("HEAD", null, null);

        // reset tail node
        tail = new OrderedListNode("TAIL", head, null);

        // header references tail in an empty LinkedList
        head.next = tail;

        // reset size to 0
        theSize = 0;

        // emptying list counts as a modification
        modCount++;
    }


    /**
     * Return true if this OrderedLinkedList contains 0 items.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return theSize == 0;
    }


    /**
     * Return the number of items in this OrderedLinkedList.
     */
    public int size() {
        return theSize;
    }


    /*
     *  Return a String representation of this OrderedLinkedList.
     *
     *  (non-Javadoc)
     *  @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";

        OrderedListNode currentNode = head.next;

        while (currentNode != tail) {
            s += currentNode.theItem.toString();

            if (currentNode.next != tail) {
                s += ", ";
            }

            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }

        return s;
    }


    /**************************************************************************
     * Inner Classes
     *************************************************************************/


    /**
     * Nested class OrderedListNode.
     * <p>
     * Encapsulates the fundamental building block of an OrderedLinkedList
     * contains a data item, and references to both the next and previous nodes
     * in the list
     */

    public static class OrderedListNode {
        Comparable theItem;
        OrderedListNode next;
        OrderedListNode previous;

        OrderedListNode(Comparable item, OrderedListNode prev, OrderedListNode next) {
            this.theItem = item;
            this.previous = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }

    }


    // TODO: Implement the nested class OrderedListNode (5 points).  This nested class
    // should be similar to the nested class ListNode of the class LinkedList, but
    // should store a data item of type Comparable rather than Object.

    public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("test");

      OrderedLinkedList listOne = new OrderedLinkedList();

      listOne.add('1');
      listOne.add('2');
      listOne.add('3');

      System.out.println(listOne + " ");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an edited version of the add method:

```
public boolean add(Comparable obj) 
{
    // TODO: Implement this method (8 points)
    OrderedListNode node = new OrderedListNode(obj, null, null);

    //if list is empty, add to beginning of list
    if (isEmpty()) 
    {
        head.next = node;
        node.next = tail;
        tail.previous = node;
        theSize++;
    }
    else
    {
        OrderedListNode pointer = head.next;
        while(pointer.theItem.compareTo(obj) < 0 && pointer != tail)
        {
            pointer = pointer.next;
        }
        if(pointer == tail)
        {
            pointer = tail.previous;
            pointer.next = node;
            node.previous = pointer;
            node.next = tail;
            tail.previous = node;
            modCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            node.previous = pointer.previous;
            node.next = pointer;
            pointer.previous.next = node;
            pointer.previous = node;
            modCount++;             
        }
        theSize++;
    }
    return true;

}
```

This should work! I think shuffling through the list instead of just finding the right spot was causing some pointer issues...this should work!

Comment: Hey MrsNickalo. Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited it to include the full code above as keeping it as just a snippet seemed to do more harm than good. Would you increment theSize within the initial If statements as well? When I try to do that, I get an 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Character cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Character and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')'.

Comment: So, I fixed that error by changing the objects you pass in to Strings (using " instead of ') because the program was treating them as Strings after you added them, causing an error when you went to compare the next one.

Comment: Okay, and I found why it's not fully working. Whenever you add the second Object, it does not execute the while loop because the pointer.next is pointing to the Tail, which is null. To fix that, simply change it to a do-while!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it misses the middle elements when printing. So listOne consisting of 1, 2, 3 only prints 1 & 3.

Comment: I figured out a fix for that! - see answer